# WPF and PowerShell: Setting selected item on ComboBox when being used with ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, powershell, combobox

I have the below combo box setup as below:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxCountry" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" Height="24" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding EnglishName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

As part of my script which to provide a bit of context is a user creation script with a templating feature I export the Selected Item to Json along with the other user details. I take the whole selected item with the below command (I have removed the other user details from the object for ease):

```
$UserObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
    "Country" = $MainScreenComboBoxCountry.SelectedItem
}
```

When I come back to import the template at a later date, my object is as below:

> Country : @{TwoLetterISORegionName=AW; EnglishName=Aruba}

And when I call that, it expands correctly as below:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $JsonObject.UserDetails.Country

TwoLetterISORegionName EnglishName
---------------------- -----------
AW                     Aruba
```

But when I try to set the combobox back to that selected item, it does not work. The command I have used is:

```
$MainScreenComboBoxCountry.SelectedItem = $JsonObject.UserDetails.Country
```

But it does not select that item. I populate the combobox when the program loads, with the below code, which works fine:

```
Function Get-CountryCodes {
    $AllCultures = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures([System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::SpecificCultures)
    $CountryDetails = @()

    $AllCultures | ForEach-Object {
        $DisplayName = $_.DisplayName.Split(“(|)”)
        $RegionInfo = New-Object System.Globalization.RegionInfo $PsItem.Name
        $CountryDetails += [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name = $RegionInfo.Name
            EnglishName = $RegionInfo.EnglishName
            TwoLetterISORegionName = $RegionInfo.TwoLetterISORegionName
        }
    }

    $Countries = $CountryDetails | Select-Object -Unique -Property TwoLetterISORegionName,EnglishName | Sort-Object EnglishName

    $Countries = $Countries | Where-Object TwoLetterISORegionName -CMatch “^[A-Z]*$”
    Return $Countries
}
$MainScreenComboBoxCountry.ItemsSource = Get-CountryCodes
```

Strangely I get no errors, but it just doesn't set the selected item.

Comment: I think you should use `$MainScreenComboBoxCountry.SelectedItem = $JsonObject.UserDetails.Country.EnglishName` because you are binding the combobox to the EnglishName property with `{Binding EnglishName}`. P.s. I also think you should change the curly 'smart-quotes' to straight ones in code.

Comment: @Theo unfortunately, that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve with the below code instead:

```
ForEach ($ComboBoxItem in $MainScreenComboBoxCountry.Items) {
            If ($ComboBoxItem.EnglishName -eq $JsonObject.UserDetails.Country.EnglishName) {
                $CorrectComboBoxItem = $ComboBoxItem
            }
        }
    $MainScreenComboBoxCountry.SelectedIndex = $MainScreenComboBoxCountry.Items.IndexOf($CorrectComboBoxItem)
```